# Как построить диаграмму зависимостей классов и интерфейсов на основе существующиего модуля

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, диаграммы

Есть ли плагин для Intellij Idea, который бы мог для модуля собираемого с помощью maven, построить диаграмму зависимостей классов и интерфейсов для текущего проекта ?

Comment: В Ultimate версии (не знаю есть ли в урезанных) есть стандартный плагин UML (в настройках/меню как Diagrams), но он не создает диаграммы на весь проект, слабо себе представляю диаграмма на 1000 классов - ничего же не рассмотришь. Плагин строит диаграмму класса или выбранного пакета (без вложенных пакетов).